# Foundation off-canvas reveal-for-large - in IE slides open on each page load

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation off-canvas and the [reveal-for-large](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#reveal-on-larger-screens) class so that the sidebar is always visible to larger screens. In Chrome and Firefox, the sidebar always appears open between page loads, which is great. However, upon each page load in Edge and IE, the sidebar first does not appear (although left margin space has been reserved for it) - and then the sidebar slides in to fill the space.

It is distracting to have this animation on each page load. Is there any way to force the sidebar to stay open in IE? Or disable the animation perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `$offcanvas-transition-length` SASS property to `0s`.